Tabular Editor: Change the Expression of a field Parameter Table / calculated Table via script
I have a table which is defind as a field Parameter (which I've customized)
TableName = "TOP-Kategorie"
Now, I'd like to update the expression
var targetTable = Model.Tables["TOP-Kategorie"];
var MyNewExpression = ReadFile(@"U:...\TabularMeasures\TOP-Kategorie.csv");  // this works
targetTable.Expression = MyNewExpression ; //not working

how do I change the exression?
Thanks!
